# Handling API design and OO sugar

Tags: javascript, api

Introductory reading:

- [Prototypes as "classes"](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/prototypes-as-classes.html)
- [OO JS](http://raynos.org/blog/5/Doing-Object-Oriented-Javascript---part-2)

Following the patterns described above I create libraries/APIs as the following

```
var Proto = {
  constructor: function () {
    this.works = true;
  },
  method: function () {
    return this.works;
  }
};
```

Now for library users to interact with my prototypes (which do not supply factory functions) they have to instantiate and initialize the object

```
// instantiate
var p = Object.create(Proto);
// initialize
p.constructor();
```

This is an unfriendly and verbose way of forcing users to instantiate and initialize my objects.

personally since I use [`pd`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd) in all my applications I have the following sugar

```
// instantiate or initialize
var p = Proto.new();
// or without bolting onto Object.prototype
var p = pd.new(Proto);
```

However I think it's unkind to force pd onto users so I'm not sure what's the best way to make my libraries usable.

1. People create new instances of `Proto` and call `.constructor` themself
2. Force people to use `pd`
3. Give `.create` style factory functions
4. Give up and use `new <Function>` and `.prototype`

1 and 2 have already been mentioned.

3 would basically be

```
Proto.create = pd.new.bind(pd, Proto);
```

4 would make me sad but confirming to a known standard way of doing things increases usability.

Generally when using non-standard OO patterns what are the easiest mechanisms to allow people to use my library in their application?

I'm currently tempted to say

```
// here is my Prototype
Proto;
// here is how you instantiate a new instance
var p = Object.create(Proto);
// here is how you initialize it
// yes instantiation and initialization are seperate and should be.
p.constructor();
// Want sugar, use pd.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, you probably make it easiest on your library clients if you use a small API that helps you with building a traditional constructor function, using syntax that looks almost like prototypes-as-classes. Example API usage:

```
// Superclass
var Person = Class.extend({
    constructor: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    describe: function() {
        return "Person called "+this.name;
    }
});

// Subclass
var Worker = Person.extend({
    constructor: function (name, title) {
        Worker.super.constructor.call(this, name);
        this.title = title;
    },
    describe: function () {
        return Worker.super.describe.call(this)+" ("+this.title+")";
    }
});
var jane = new Worker("Jane", "CTO");
```

Implementations:

- [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
- I’ve reimplemented Resig’s API, in a way that is possibly easier to understand: [rauschma/class-js](https://github.com/rauschma/class-js)

Comment: but then that's basically just #4. I'm creating objects that are functions. I really don't want to do that.

Comment: @Raynos: True, but it’s what everyone else does. I’d prefer that everyone would use prototypes as classes (PACs), but it probably won’t ever happen. However, [class literals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:classes) will likely make it into ES6 and then everything _looks_ like PACs. I find that acceptable, because it keeps things compatible. What is under the hood _is_ structured quite clearly. I just wouldn’t want to manage it. If ES6 does that for me – then fine.

Comment: I've opted for ["here's how you instantiate and initialize PAC](http://raynos.org/blog/7/Doing-Object-Oriented-Javascript---part-3). Now that you know, you can use my code, it all makes sense."

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is providing the `new(Prototype, [arguments])` function as per the "use pd" option. It should even not be that bad from a dependency point of view (since you could have packaged this function separately anyway and is has just a couple of lines of code)

Offering a special function also fits in a sort of historic perspective. If you go way back to Smalltalk or even in more recent cases like Python you have separate functions for object creation (new) and initialization (init, the constructor) and the only only reason we don't notice the separation is because they provide syntactic sugar for object instantiation.

Comment: Should this `.new` function be added to every Prototype "class" I create or should it just be bolted onto `Object.prototype.new` (and bad programmers be damned!). Basically bolting on `.new` to all my "classes" ruins the point of having `Object.prototype.new`.

Comment: You could follow the ancient tradition and put your framework functions in a master parent class (forcing all your classes to inherit from it) or you could just create a plain non-method function like pd.new

Comment: Wait what, "master parent class" "forcing inheritance".

Comment: Well, most OO languages have gotten away with having an Object class that everyone is forced to inherit from. You can use the sugar you have by bolting things to Object.prototype or you can make things your own way (with a new Object subclass and the rest done without the existing sugar). My original point was just that most OO languages so far employ tons of sugar to make things look simple so using a lightweight library to do things when there is no sugar is actually not that bad.